# JSON and JavaScript - how to read my list by using json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I don't know why I can not read object by using below way

```
function loadData(){
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(Index, entry) {
            mem = new user(entry.name, entry.age, entry.location);
            userList.push(mem);
        });
    });
    return false;
}

function fillTable(){
    var html = "";
    console.log(userList);
    console.log(userList[0].name);
    $.each(userList,function(index , user){
       console.log(index);
        html += '<tr>';
        html +=  '<th>'+this.name+'</th>';
        html +=  '<th>'+this.age+'</th>';
        html +=  '<th>'+this.loca+'</th>';
        html += '</tr>'

        console.log(this.name);
    });
    $("#listTable").html(html);
}
```

the screen shot of above result in console is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwZhF.png)

Comment: You cannot access it as `entry.name` as it is not an js object though its an array. What server side language are you using? If it is PHP, try `json_encode()`;

Comment: I didn't used server     all code is run in local

Comment: You need to show the sample structure of your JSON file then...

Comment: [
  {
    "name": "이름",
    "age": "나이",
    "location": "지역"
  },
  {
    "name": "곽성훈",
    "age": "28",
    "location": "영등포"
  }
]

Comment: this is  json file source

Comment: By server I meant server side scripting. try `console.log(data);`  after second line and show the output.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at fillTable (main.html:116)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.html:95)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: this is the error message

Answer (score 2):

Call fillTable in `loadData` function, as `getJson` is async

```
function loadData(){
            $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(Index, entry) {
                    mem = new user(entry.name, entry.age, entry.location);
                    userList.push(mem);
                });
fillTable(); -- call it here
            });

            return false;
        }
```

Comment: wowowowowowowowowowowwo    olololololololololololololololol      I solve this problem    I don't know why i should code like this and  the reason of this but it's working    thanks~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: To understand async vs sync refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean and and please accept as answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
   function loadData(){
        $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(Index, entry) {
                mem = new user(entry.name, entry.age, entry.location);
                userList.push(mem);
            });
      fillTable()
        });

        return false;
    }      

   function fillTable(){
        var html = "";
        console.log(userList);
        console.log(userList[0].name);
        var self = this;
        $.each(userList,function(index , user){
           console.log(index);
            html += '<tr>';
            html +=  '<th>'+self.name+'</th>';
            html +=  '<th>'+self.age+'</th>';
            html +=  '<th>'+self.loca+'</th>';
            html += '</tr>'

            console.log(self.name);
        });
```

}

**this** will point to inside function, you need to delcare **this** outside this in outside function.

Try this it may work